# If $y=a(-c+x)(-d+x)$ and "the co-efficient of $x$ is $b$", then find $a$ in terms of $c$ and $d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following:
$$y = a\,\left(  - c+x\right) \,\left(  - d+x\right)$$
and that "the co-efficient of $x$ is $b$", and asked to define $a$ in terms of $c$ and $d$, why is the answer:
$$a = \frac{-b}{c+d}$$

When I attempt to solve this myself, I end up with a series of unlike terms.  What happened to $x$?  Is the book I’m working from wrong?

Comment: I think I understand but I would like to clarify something before I make my assumption. Do you mean to have a negative anywhere in that fraction?

Comment: I will go ahead and make my assumption. If you write your polynomial in standard form (expanded form), you should see the coefficient is something else other than b. So you will set that expression equal to b and solve for a.

Comment: Nothing happened to $x$.  If you expan $a(-c+x)(-d+x)$ you are going to get something of the form $y = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are all some combination of $a,d,c$.  The coefficient of $x$, what I labeled as $\beta$, is some combination of $a,c,d$.  The book is calling that coefficient $b$.  So you should have $b = $some combination of $a,c,d$.  Solve for $a$.

Comment: "when I attempt to solve this myself i end up with a series of unlike terms"  what do you end up with.  We can't tell you what you did wrong (and yes, you, did something wrong, not the book) if you don't tell us what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have $y = a(x-c)(x-d)$ 
$$\implies y = a(x^2 - (c+d)x +cd) = ax^2 - a(c+d)x +acd)$$
We are told the coefficient of $x$ is $b$ so we have:
$$-a(c+d) = b$$
and then rearranging for $a$ gives:
$$a=\frac{-b}{c+d}$$

Comment: Thanks @Ogglie!  I understand your expansion, but there is something im missing which makes it difficult for me to follow the part about the co-efficient of x being b.  If the co-efficient of x is b, then isnt the next step to substitute $-a(c+d)$ with $b$?  Can you elaborate on the rearrangement process?

Comment: The penny just dropped.  Given the answer, the instruction to define a in terms of c and d appears incomplete, or misleading.  Perhaps i am still too unfamiliar with the conventions of mathematical discourse to have understood that $x$ and $y$ could be ignored, also the rightmost term in the expansion $cd$.  I see how it is possible to equate b with the middle term and solve for $a$, but I'm confused about where in the challenge it is permissible to ignore all other terms, or is this implicit in the operation?

Comment: I think I understand your confusion.

Let's say we have that:
$$ax^2 + bx +c = px^2 + qx +r$$
It's important to understand that $x$ is a variable so this relation holds true for any value of $x$.
Rearranging gives:
$$(a-p)x^2+(b-q)x+c-r = 0$$
Logically we can see that for this to be true no matter what the value of $x$ is, we must have $a=p,b=q,c=r$ but I will prove this regardless.
This is true for all x so let's set $x=0$, then:
$$c-r=0 \implies c=r$$
Substituting this back tells us:
$$(a-p)x^2 + (b-q)x = 0$$

Comment: Now let's set $x=1$:
$$a-p+b-q=0 \implies a-p = -(b-q)$$
Again, we substitute this back into our quadratic:
$$-(b-q)x^2 + (b-q)x = 0$$
If we now set $x=2$:
$$-4(b-q) + (b-q) = 0$$
rearranging gives:
$$b=q$$
So, we can conclude that if two quadratics are equal, so are their $x$ coefficients, and, in fact, their $x^2$ and $x^0$ coefficients (by the same reasoning).
Therefore, if the $x$ coefficient of $y$ is $b$, since $y = ax^2 - a(c+d)x +acd$, we must have:
$b = -a(c+d)$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!  What is it called when we equate something into an equation like that?  Turns out my initial confusion was to interpret the challenge to mean that I should substitute one value for another.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this. If you mean noticing that b=q then this is called "comparing coefficients".